# Counting score with swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, count, label, textfield

Now, my problem is that when I am trying to count a score line if a person writes something that is not the same as "42" in a textfield (which will be the same as the label.text) they will get punished by 1 minus point. If I have written something which is not "42" it gives me 1 minus point for it but only the first time. If I do it again the scoreline will not change so I will be stuck at the -1 scoreline.

How can i do so every time I write something which is not "42" it will give me a -1 point even if I already got a -1 score?

(As you can see I have set the label.text to be the same as textfield.text if you are wondering)

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        // MARK: PROBERTIES
        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            textField.delegate = self
            imagePicker.delegate = self

        }


        func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            textField.resignFirstResponder()

            return true
        }
        func textFieldDidEndEditing(textfield: UITextField) {
            label.text = textField.text
            var score = 0


            if textField.text != "42" {
                score -= 1
            }

            // MARK: if-statements

            if label.text! == "42" {
                label1.text = "You are correct"
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                score += 10
            }

            if label.text != "42" {
                label1.text = "Damn, wrong"
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

            }

            if label.text!.isEmpty {
                label1.text = "Still waiting for an answer..."

            }

            if label.text == "happiness" {
                label1.text = "It is not a key element in the meaning of life"

            }

            if label.text == "to be happy" {
                label1.text = "i would rather be rich"

            }

            if label.text == "money" {
                label1.text = "there is more in this world than money"

            }

            if label.text == "There is no meaning of life" {
                label1.text = "There is a meaning to everything"

            }

            if label.text == "there is no meaning of life"
            {
                label1.text = "there is a meaning to everything"

            }

            if label.text == "to be rich" {
                label1.text = "Money does not solve every problem"


            }

            var scoreString = String(score)
            scoreLabel.text = "Your score is \(scoreString)"


        }
```

Comment: Hi what exactly do you mean by "How can i do so every time I write something which is not "42" it will give me a -1 point even if I already got a -1 score?", like for example you have 100 score, not typing 42 will give you 99 score and if you dont type 42 again then it will remain at 99? Or 98?

Comment: What I mean is that i only can trigger the "-1" (if i write something which is not "42") and "+10" (if i write "42") once. For example i start with the scoreline 0 and write something which is not equal to 42 then i end the textfield editing and my scoreLabel changes to "Your score -1" but when i start editing again and write something which is not equal to "42" then my scoreLabel will still look the same "Your score -1"

Answer (score 0):

Add a connection from your ViewController object to the text field's Editing Changed outlet. Whatever method you hook up to that will be called when the field's text changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something else but I thought I'd share what got me out of trouble a while ago with my labels holding Integers which changed back to strings that I wasn't aware of.

```
var pointsCount = 0

func addPoints(_ points: NSInteger)
{
    if let text = self.pointsLabel.text, var pointsCount = Int(text)
    {
        pointsCount += points
        pointsLabel.text = "\(pointsCount)"
    }
}
```

To add 2 points simply use

```
addPoints(2)
```